# Delete JNLP file after it's get executed

Tags: java, jnlp

Is there anyway to delete the JNLP file after it's get executed.

When my application opens in a browser, a JNLP file is downloaded. So I don't want to keep the duplicate JNLP files so for that I want to delete the JNLP file after it's get executed

Answer (score 0):

The jnlp downloads a jar with a Java application. That application could delete the jnlp file.

Comment: Right.. I tried the same.. Let's say the jnlp file is downloaded in users download folder.. That java application can find the users download folder and delete the file. But if user when downloads the jnlp file keep in different folder other than download folder then how the java application knows the path.